# Why only / path works in AKS with NGINX Ingress Controller

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks, nginx-ingress

I had a clean Azure subscription and created AKS using Standard SKU and very basic setup (2 D2as_v4 nodes, default settings). Installed NGINX like:

```
helm install ingress-nginx ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx
```

Then put there a dummy app and made it accessible via Ingress + ClusterIP service:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: ingress-demo
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: ingress-demo
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: ingress-demo
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: ingress-demo
        image: mcr.microsoft.com/azuredocs/aks-helloworld:v1
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: ingress-demo
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
  - port: 80
  selector:
    app: ingress-demo
```

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: development-ingress
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: ingress-demo
            port: 
              number: 80
```

This **works** and I can access the dummy app on the Public IP assigned to my Ingress.

### Issue:

I cannot access my app using any non-defalt path configuration. I get `Error: Request timed out`
for anything else than `/`. This Ingress change does not work for me:

```
- path: /foo
```

Same issue using regex:

```
annotations:
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
...
    - path: /dev(/|$)(.*)
```

### UPDATE

I have tried multiple fixes suggested in the [GitHub issue mentioned by silent](https://github.com/Azure/AKS/issues/2903).
Using following option makes `/foo` path work:

```
--set controller.service.annotations."service\.beta\.kubernetes\.io/azure-load-balancer-health-probe-request-path"=/healthz
```

But it still doesn't work for regex. To make path like `/dev(/|$)(.*)` operable you need either change Azure Load Balancer probe [from HTTP to TCP](https://github.com/Azure/AKS/issues/2903#issuecomment-1106784221) (keeping the port) or to install NGINX controller with this flag:

```
--set controller.service.externalTrafficPolicy=Local
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite sure but it sounds like you ran into this issue: https://github.com/Azure/AKS/issues/2903

The solution was posted in this post: https://github.com/Azure/AKS/issues/2903#issuecomment-1109758644

Comment: It works. Thanks again! 

`helm install nginx-ingress ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx --set controller.service.externalTrafficPolicy=Local`