# Only path / works in AKS ingress

Tags: azure, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, azure-aks, nginx-ingress

I surfed on many websites, stackoverflow post and others but cannot find the workaround. Using AKS 1.23.8 and Ingress installed with `helm install ingress nginx-stable/nginx-ingress --set controller.service.annotations."service\.beta\.kubernetes\.io/azure-load-balancer-health-probe-request-path"=/healthz --set controller.service.externalTrafficPolicy=Local`

and this is the multiple paths ingress rule :

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: az-ingress
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: k8s.test.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: azure-vote-front
            port: 
              number: 80
      - path: /hello
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: hello-world-service
            port: 
              number: 80
```

Which was showed in this post :
[Why only / path works in AKS with NGINX Ingress Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72085831/why-only-path-works-in-aks-with-nginx-ingress-controller) and https://github.com/Azure/AKS/issues/2907
Path **/** works but path **/hello** return `Cannot GET /hello`

If i use different host for each service, it works like a charm :

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: az-ingress
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: k8s.test.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: azure-vote-front
            port: 
              number: 80
  - host: k8s.test2.example.com
    http:
      paths:            
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: hello-world-service
            port: 
              number: 80
```

what could be the issue ?

This is the log :
[image]

Comment: @HarshManvar yea thats also what came up in my mind. i then changed the path rule by moving /hello to the first path-rule and path / to second path-rule. also tried using pathType ImplementationSpecific but still no luck

Answer (score -1):

Hows your luck if you try "pathType: Exact"  for /hello